# Knockout.js Tracking Selected Checkboxes

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, knockout.js

I have a html grid that returns a checkbox with each row.  Currently I have these bound with knockout to my viewmodel.  I've gotten far enough to capture the id of what is checked for a row but I'm not sure how to make Knockout give me a list of all rows checked and the content of every cell for the row.

Ultimately the intent is to let users select multiple rows from this table and then export that data.  So I need a good way to gather the entire row up.

I've only been using Knockout for about a week so am I trying to get it to track something that perhaps I'd be better of just looping through the table with javascript?

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: projectListing">
   <tr data-bind="css: $data.rowclass">
      <td><input type="checkbox" data-bind="value: $data.id, checked: $root.selectedRows, click: $root.toggleRowSelection"/></td>
      <td data-bind="text: $data.SORT_ID"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: $data.PROJ_ID"></td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

*I know that code isn't enough to go on but I had to put something in here so I could list a link to jsFiddle.

I have a fiddle going that represents this to show code I have so far.  What I'd like to do with this fiddle is each time I check the checkbox, the entire row content should show up.  That would get me to the place I need to be in my real project.

Any ideas on how to go about this?

Here is what I have so far.

**http://jsfiddle.net/robhortn/ad2Yu/4/**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of getting the id with the checked binding, you can create a selectedItems computed to get the selected items objects

```
self.selectedItems = ko.computed(function() {
    return self.availableItems().filter(function(item) {
        return item.Selected();
    });
});
```

Html

```
Selected Books:

<div data-bind="foreach: $root.selectedItems">
    <span data-bind="text: Name"></span>
    <br/>
</div>
```

[See this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3pVMU/)

Comment: That makes sense.  If I want the other 'fields' such as the id and price values, can I also get them at the same time?  Essentially outputting the entire row that was selected?

Comment: Got it!  I figured out the rest of what I needed from the very clear example you gave here.  Thanks!